# Compound addition assignment operator treating quoted numbers as . . . numbers?

Tags: javascript, string, browser, numbers, interpreter

So I'm reading a book on JavaScript called *JavaScript: The Web Warrior Series*. In the book, they state that the compound addition assignment operator treats quoted numbers as numbers, not as strings, combining their values, not concatenating them. Testing this in Google Chrome, I discovered this to be incorrect. Has there ever been a browser whose JavaScript interpreter processes a quoted number as a number through the compound addition assignment operator?

Thanks!!! :)

Comment: The page you're referencing can be found on the first link [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The+Web+Warrior%22+%22compound+addition+assignment%22). The book is just plain wrong, though, that would violate the official specification and would surely break many scripts. It would also be clearer to use the word "concatenate" rather than "combine" when referring to putting two strings together to form a single longer string.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I used the word "combining" because the book said that the compound assignment operator treats quoted numbers as numbers, not strings, which would get concatenated by the addition operator. Now I know for sure that the compound addition assignment operator treats quoted numbers as strings, concatenating them, not combing their values! (-:

Comment: Yep, definitely a problem with the book, not with the person trying to learn from the book :P

Comment: It is interesting that a book that is used in colleges can be so grossly wrong like that.